# Login With Facebook hybridauth

Tags: php, hybridauth

I have an issue when login with Facebook.
--When first time I log in with Facebook it redirects me to the Facebook login page and I enter my username and password and I get a response no problem it's fine

--But the second time when I log in with Facebook it did not redirect me to the Facebook login page I want to reauthenticate every time when clicking on login with facebook.

I'm using PHP hybridauth library.

```
$this->hybridauth->logoutAllProviders();//this did not logout me completely
```

Actually, I want to log out from web.facebook.com

Comment: _"But the second time when I log in with Facebook it did not redirect me to the Facebook login page"_ - users are not supposed to be bothered with the login dialog again, if the app is not asking for any new permissions. This works as designed.

Comment: _"this did not logout me completely"_ - an app can only log the user out of Facebook, if the user logged in to Facebook itself while logging in to your app. If they were logged into Facebook before already, then you can only log them out of your app, not out of Facebook itself. Also works as designed.